convert dict value to int
How Can I resolve this error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'dict_values'
which is related to below line:
Real_Expectation_Value = (2 * rawResult[0].value.counts["0"] / sum(rawResult[0].value.counts.values()) - 1)

sorry. I am new in python and appreciate any help. The following code is the main code:
from classiq import set_execution_preferences
from classiq import create_model
from classiq.execution import ExecutionPreferences
NumShots=[1000,2000,4000,8000,6000]
RealExpect=[]
Theoretical_realexpectation=[]
for numShots in NumShots:
    quantumModel=create_model(main)
    quantum_model_with_execution_preferences = 
    set_execution_preferences(
    quantumModel, ExecutionPreferences(
    num_shots=numShots, job_name="Hadamard Test", random_seed=767
     ),
    )
    synthesize(quantumModel)
    rawResult=execute(synthesize(quantumModel)).result()
    countS=rawResult[0].value.counts
    Real_Expectation_Value = (2 * rawResult[0].value.counts["0"] / sum(rawResult[0].value.counts.values()) - 1)


Thanks @TomKarzes.  I did not split it. two last lines actually is one line in jupyther

Unable to replicate as classiq cannot be installed in the latest Python version (3.12.4). Even if it was, the code shown in the question would not be runnable. Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example

Thanks. It is write this library works with Python 3.11 as developer has said

If if you tried running your code with Python 3.11, it would fail with a NameError exception

Maybe you need to convert dict_values to a list, so try this:
Real_Expectation_Value = (2 * countS["0"] / sum(list(countS.values())) - 1)

or you can try printing sum(countS.values()) to make sure, that it's an int
